# How to use apt on a network using only https?

Tags: apt, https

Everybody.

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on the computer I use in the company I'm working at.

The net is going without any problem, but when I try the famous:

## sudo apt update command

I see these errors:

```
 Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                               
  Le fichier signé en clair n'est pas valable, ce qui a été reçu est « NOSPLIT ». Peut-être le réseau nécessite-t-il une authentification.
```

Please, can somebody tell me how I can use apt over this network ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on the net and I found these secured mirrors: deb https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: Could you please share where did you look for those mirrors?